# Determining the last row in a collection in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, foreach

Quick question:

I'm building a JSON string by iterating over a collection and using string builder (yes, there probably are smarter ways to do this, but debugging linq gives me a headache). As I build an array, I have to put a comma after each item.

Currently I do this by incrementing an int before each row is handled in foreach, and if the int matches the number of rows in the collection I don't add a comma.

```
StringBuilder bob = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
foreach(Item m in Rows){
     i++;
     bob.Append(string.Format("{{ foo: '{0}', bar: '{1}' }}", m.foo, m.bar));
     bob.Append(i == Rows.Count() ? "" : ",")
}
```

I'm wondering if there some smarter way of determining if a current object is the last in a collection?

**UPDATE:**

Answered. It's really a shame I can only pick one, as there were lots of good answers. In particular Matthew Watson's answer was probably the closest to what I was originally looking for - a way to directly ask the collection if this is the last item. However, in reviewing all the other answers I've decided that String.Join is just better, and replacing the foreach with Linq is just better again. Thanks for all your help everyone!

Comment: A bit of code would help with providing an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx) for this.

It concatenates a passed in array of strings using a passed in delimiter, omitting it for the last value.

Something like:

```
var vals = string.Join(",", Rows.Select(
                              i => string.Format(
                                      "{{ foo: '{0}', bar: '{1}' }}", 
                                      i.foo, 
                                      i.bar)));
```

Comment: string.Join seems like the cleanest way alright (and everyone has suggested it) but it means I have to add my items to a collection before joining. Oh well. Probably for the best!

Comment: @roryok - `string.Join(",", Rows.Select(string.Format...))`

Comment: but then I'm back into linq territory, where the temptation is to abandon the foreach entirely and use purely Linq. That's when the headaches start =)

Comment: Yep you don't need a separate collection as long as you have an IEnumerable<String> you can use.

Comment: @roryok - LINQ is not the answer for _everything_, but it _does_ make life easier on occasion.

Comment: @oded it does, but on this occasion there are a couple of additional steps in that foreach that make the ensuing pure linq version a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.length.aspx) to concatenate the commas? Edit: Since you've added code now i see that you're already using the `StringBuilder`, so this works:

```
StringBuilder bob = new StringBuilder();
foreach(Item m in Rows)
{
     bob.Append(string.Format("{{ foo: '{0}', bar: '{1}' }}", m.foo, m.bar));
}
if(bob.Length != 0) bob.Length -= 1;
```

Another way is using [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string csv = string.Join(",", array);
```

Comment: a bit like doing a substring? that seems icky

Comment: @roryok: It's an efficient and readable way to remove the last char. A `Substring` is something different, it is error-prone(wrong indices) and less readable.

Answer (score 0):

I usually track the first item, and include the comma at the beginning of the loop.

```
bool first = true;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (first)
    {
        sb.Append(',');
        first = false;
    }

    sb.Append(item);
}
```

Note that the above can be converted to:

```
sb.Append(string.Join(",", items));
```

**EDIT** Since you added your code, you can change your loop into a single statement:

```
String bob = string.Join(",", Rows.Select(r => string.Format("{{ foo: '{0}', bar: '{1}' }}", r.foo, r.bar)));
```

It looks like you're trying to write out JSON. There are libraries for this that are possibly worth looking at.

Comment: seems like the first approach is much the same as counting rows. maybe slightly more efficient

Comment: @roryok, yes, it can be much more efficient, if that matters. Your code calls Count() each time around. I'll point out that I'll only use this approach if I cannot use Join. Generally, if performance matters, I'd avoid allocating the large string and write directly to a stream. Creating all these temporary strings and then collecting them is wasteful.

Comment: Thanks drew, your pure linq implementation is very clean but my actual foreach is more complex than this simple example, and the ensuing linq hurts my brain just trying to read it.

Comment: @roryok, I figured as much, which is why I included a loop in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a single item per line you can do

```
jsonString.ReplaceAll("\n",",");
```

Comment: json values can have newlines in them

Comment: They will still have a multicode char line terminator that you can filter out. Just because you can't see it doesn't mean it's not there.

Comment: lets not get into any religious debates ;)

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of good answers already, but I just wanted to mention a useful general-purpose class that would help with this and many related problems.

[Jon Skeet's SmartEnumerable class](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/07/27/smart-enumerations.aspx) lets you interrogate an enumerator to find its index and whether it is the first or last item in the enumeration. ([Here's an implementation](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/index.html).)

Using a SmartEnumberable, the code would look like this:

```
var result = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in data.AsSmartEnumerable())
{
    result.Append(item.Value);

    if (!item.IsLast)
    {
        result.Append(", ");
    }
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (var item in data.AsSmartEnumerable())
{
    if (!item.IsFirst)
    {
        result.Append(", ");
    }

    result.Append(item.Value);
}
```